# Add Data to WebResponse

Tags: c#, response, webrequest, outputstream, webresponse

I sent some data by webrequest POST method. I know how to catch and modify the data, but I can't put it back to response and send it back to the client.  I tried 4 ways to do it, but nothing worked.

SERVER PART

```
this.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream);
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();
if (x != "")
{
    string xml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x);
    XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    EditXml(xmlInput);
    String str = "This is testing";
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] b = encoding.GetBytes(str);
    Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    //Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    //Response.Clear();
    //Response.BufferOutput = true;
    //xmlInput.Save(Response.OutputStream);
    //Response.Flush();
```

CLIENT PART

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetByteCount(data);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Close();
            responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string received = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Up there I'm showing two ways how I tried to put data to response, but neither works... so am I totally wrong, am I just missing something simple in the last step? :-)

Comment: As far as i'm aware, you send the actual POST when you call "WebResponse response = yourWebRequest.GetResponse();". I don't see any point where you're doing that here. Try looking at the following MSDN post; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: Hello i didnt put the client code here but i updated my ask .... so i can send request and data inside i allready known how to catch them on server part after that i modified trhem in EditXml method but i didnt put code here and than i wana include this edited text to respons and my ask is how i wil do that... i can allready receive the respons but its empy ... i dont know hopw to add some data or text into response...?